# Menu with include in classic asp

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic

Hi I have a menu in aspx page which works finely. So, I create a asp page called classicmenu.asp which consists of this

```
           <head>
    <script type="text/javascript"           
        src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script> 
     <script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
  $('#menu').load('Menuin.aspx');
  });
      </script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <div id="menu" >
   <label runat="server">afggh</label>
  </div>
  <label runat="server">asd</label>
   </body> 
 </html>
```

Even here it works fine. I can see the menu . So, once include this in another asp page, I just get the labels defined in classicmenu.asp but not the menu i define in aspx page. So, can u guys help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Where in the folder structure is the page that includes `classicmenu.asp`?  If it's not in the same directory as `Menuin.aspx`, then the JS won't know where to find it when trying to `load()`.